# tikzpictures positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am having trouble trying to position tikzpictures in their correct position...
I want to place the 3 plots with the green filling in a single line above (with the alpha/2 right below), and the 3 plots with the yellow filling in a single line below (with the alpha/2 right below)... how could I specify here a new line?? I have tried using \nodes but for some reason it does not work.

There is something I am missing here, since I specify the width of the minipages to be \linewidth, and the paperwidth of the document is slightly more than the width of 3 plots in line.

The following MWE produces this figure:
[image]

However, I would like that it produced a picture similar to this one (which I have made manually):
[image]

The code I have so far is the following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[paperwidth=32cm,paperheight=15cm]{geometry}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
    \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}



\begin{document}

{\large
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \textcolor{green!70!black}{Tissue-specific expression}\\
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
            no markers, domain=0:12, samples=100,
            axis lines*=left, xlabel=\empty, ylabel=\empty,
            every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
            every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
            height=5cm, width=9cm,
            xtick={2,8}, ytick=\empty,
            xticklabels={{\footnotesize $\mu$1},{\footnotesize $\mu$2}},
            enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top]
            \addplot [fill=green!70!black, draw=none, domain=2.75:3.65] {gauss(2,0.5)}
            \closedcycle;
            \addplot [fill=green!70!black, draw=none, domain=4.9:6.5] {gauss(8,1)}
            \closedcycle;
            \addplot [cyan!50!black] {gauss(2,0.5)};
            \addplot [cyan!50!black] {gauss(8,1)};
            \addplot[<->] coordinates {(1.25,0.2) (2.75,0.2)};
            \node at (axis cs: 2,0.2) [font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt, above] {$\sigma 1$};
            \addplot[<->] coordinates {(6.5,0.12) (9.5,0.12)};
            \node at (axis cs: 8,0.12) [font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt, above] {$\sigma 2$};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}\quad%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
            no markers, domain=0:25, samples=100,
            axis lines*=left, xlabel=\empty, ylabel=\empty,
            every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
            every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
            height=5cm, width=9cm,
            xtick={2,8,19}, ytick=\empty,
            xticklabels={{\footnotesize $\mu$1},{\footnotesize $\mu$2},{\footnotesize $\mu$3}},
            enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top]
            \addplot [fill=green!70!black, draw=none, domain=2.75:3.65] {gauss(2,0.5)}
            \closedcycle;
            \addplot [fill=green!70!black, draw=none, domain=4.9:6.5] {gauss(8,1)}
            \closedcycle;
            \addplot [fill=green!70!black, draw=none, domain=9.5:11.1] {gauss(8,1)}
            \closedcycle;
            \addplot [fill=green!70!black, draw=none, domain=13:16] {gauss(19,2)}
            \closedcycle;
            \addplot [cyan!50!black] {gauss(2,0.5)};
            \addplot [cyan!50!black] {gauss(8,1)};
            \addplot [cyan!50!black] {gauss(19,2)};
            \addplot[<->] coordinates {(1.25,0.2) (2.75,0.2)};
            \node at (axis cs: 2,0.2) [font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt, above] {$\sigma 1$};
            \addplot[<->] coordinates {(6.5,0.12) (9.5,0.12)};
            \node at (axis cs: 8,0.12) [font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt, above] {$\sigma 2$};
            \addplot[<->] coordinates {(16,0.04) (22,0.04)};
            \node at (axis cs: 19,0.04) [font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt, above] {$\sigma 3$};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}\quad%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
            no markers, domain=0:25, samples=100,
            axis lines*=left, xlabel=\empty, ylabel=\empty,
            every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
            every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
            height=5cm, width=9cm,
            xtick={2,5,19}, ytick=\empty,
            xticklabels={{\footnotesize $\mu$1},{\footnotesize $\mu$2},{\footnotesize $\mu$3}},
            enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top]
            \addplot [fill=green!70!black, draw=none, domain=2.75:3.65] {gauss(2,0.5)}
            \closedcycle;
            \addplot [fill=green!70!black, draw=none, domain=2:3.5] {gauss(5,1)}
            \closedcycle;
            \addplot [fill=green!70!black, draw=none, domain=6.5:8] {gauss(5,1)}
            \closedcycle;
            \addplot [fill=green!70!black, draw=none, domain=13:16] {gauss(19,2)}
            \closedcycle;
            \addplot [cyan!50!black] {gauss(2,0.5)};
            \addplot [cyan!50!black] {gauss(5,1)};
            \addplot [cyan!50!black] {gauss(19,2)};
            \addplot[<->] coordinates {(1.25,0.2) (2.75,0.2)};
            \node at (axis cs: 2,0.2) [font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt, above] {$\sigma 1$};
            \addplot[<->] coordinates {(3.5,0.12) (6.5,0.12)};
            \node at (axis cs: 5,0.12) [font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt, above] {$\sigma 2$};
            \addplot[<->] coordinates {(16,0.04) (22,0.04)};
            \node at (axis cs: 19,0.04) [font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt, above] {$\sigma 3$};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        {\small {$\alpha$}/2=0.025}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \textcolor{yellow!60!black}{Ubiquitous expression}\\
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
            no markers, domain=0:10, samples=100,
            axis lines*=left, xlabel=\empty, ylabel=\empty,
            every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
            every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
            height=5cm, width=9cm,
            xtick=5, xticklabels={\footnotesize $\mu$1},
            ytick=\empty,
            enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top]
            \addplot [fill=yellow!60!black, draw=none, domain=1.5:3.5] {gauss(5,1)}
            \closedcycle;
            \addplot [fill=yellow!60!black, draw=none, domain=6.5:8.5] {gauss(5,1)}
            \closedcycle;
            \addplot [cyan!50!black] {gauss(5,1)};
            \addplot[<->] coordinates {(3.5,0.1) (6.5,0.1)};
            \node at (axis cs: 5,0.1) [font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt, above] {$\sigma 1$};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}\quad%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
            no markers, domain=0:10, samples=100,
            axis lines*=left, xlabel=\empty, ylabel=\empty,
            every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
            every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
            height=5cm, width=9cm,
            xtick={3,6}, ytick=\empty,
            xticklabels={{\footnotesize $\mu$1},{\footnotesize $\mu$2}},
            enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top]
            \addplot [fill=yellow!60!black, draw=none, domain=3.75:4.65] {gauss(3,0.5)}
            \closedcycle;
            \addplot [fill=yellow!60!black, draw=none, domain=2.5:4.5] {gauss(6,1)}
            \closedcycle;
            \addplot [cyan!50!black] {gauss(3,0.5)};
            \addplot [cyan!50!black] {gauss(6,1)};
            \addplot[<->] coordinates {(2.25,0.2) (3.75,0.2)};
            \node at (axis cs: 3,0.2) [font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt, above] {$\sigma 1$};
            \addplot[<->] coordinates {(4.5,0.12) (7.5,0.12)};
            \node at (axis cs: 6,0.12) [font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt, above] {$\sigma 2$};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}\quad%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
            no markers, domain=0:15, samples=100,
            axis lines*=left, xlabel=\empty, ylabel=\empty,
            every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
            every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
            height=5cm, width=9cm,
            xtick={2,5,10}, ytick=\empty,
            xticklabels={{\footnotesize $\mu$1},{\footnotesize $\mu$2},{\footnotesize $\mu$3}},
            enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top]
            \addplot [fill=yellow!60!black, draw=none, domain=2.75:3.65] {gauss(2,0.5)}
            \closedcycle;
            \addplot [fill=yellow!60!black, draw=none, domain=2:3.5] {gauss(5,1)}
            \closedcycle;
            \addplot [fill=yellow!60!black, draw=none, domain=6.5:8] {gauss(5,1)}
            \closedcycle;
            \addplot [fill=yellow!60!black, draw=none, domain=4:6.9] {gauss(10,2)}
            \closedcycle;
            \addplot [cyan!50!black] {gauss(2,0.5)};
            \addplot [cyan!50!black] {gauss(5,1)};
            \addplot [cyan!50!black] {gauss(10,2)};
            \addplot[<->] coordinates {(1.25,0.2) (2.75,0.2)};
            \node at (axis cs: 2,0.2) [font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt, above] {$\sigma 1$};
            \addplot[<->] coordinates {(3.5,0.12) (6.5,0.12)};
            \node at (axis cs: 5,0.12) [font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt, above] {$\sigma 2$};
            \addplot[<->] coordinates {(7,0.04) (13,0.04)};
            \node at (axis cs: 10,0.04) [font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt, above] {$\sigma 1$};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        {\scriptsize {$\alpha$}/2=0.025}
\end{minipage}%
}   
\end{document}
```

Once this issue is solved, I would like to convert the resulting pdf with a proper density setting, which I have no idea how... but this is secondary, as I can always print the screen or something... Thanks!

Comment: How should LaTeX how big a pixel is? This depends on the density, the dpi (dots per inch) settings when you convert the document to a raster picture.

Comment: So there is no way to specify the size of the document?

Comment: You can specify the size in length units (the TeX usuals: `pt`, `cm`, `in`, `mm`, `bp`, `sp`) and then convert the resulting PDF with a proper `density` setting. By the way, you better split up your question in two: One for the conversion of a *TeX output to certain-sized PNG (or whatever) and one for the `pgfplots` stuff. — What happened to [Create pngs specifying dimensions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134935)?

Comment: Could you explain step by step how to "convert the resulting pdf with a proper density setting"?
Also I'd appreciate if anyone knows how to specify a new line to have the plots arranged as described above? Thanks

Comment: nobody knows? I was hoping placing tikzpictures and creating a png out of them would be a really trivial thing...

Comment: anybody knows please?? at least how to correctly place the plots? I would really appreciate it..

Comment: remove these lines for a line break inside minipage `\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two parts to this answer. The first one is about using `groupplots` tp organise the  plots in a 3x2 grid, the second about a way of converting to PNG.

## groupplots

You could use the `groupplots` library to arrange the plots. See section **5.5 Grouping plots** in the manual.

`groupplots` is great for cases where you want to organise several plots in a grid, such as here. You use a `groupplot` environment instead of `axis`, and start a new axis with `\nextgroupplot`. In the options to the `groupplot` enviroment you can specify settings that should be the same for all the sub axes, such as width/height, style of axis lines etc.

With `group style={group size=3 by 2}` you set the number of columns in the grid to 3, and the number of rows to 2. In the `group style` one can also define the distance between the plots, with `horizontal sep` and `vertical sep`.

I've tidied up the code a little bit. Other customisations could be done, for example one could define a `\newcommand` to draw the arrow with the sigma on top, but I haven't done that. What I have done:

- Defined four new styles:

  - `sigmalabel` - for the nodes with `$\sigma 1$
  - `tissue`- for the `\closedcycle` plots in the first three subplots, defining color and `draw=none`
  - `ubiq` - similar to `tissue`, for the last three
  - `plotline` - just color of the plotted lines
- Moved all common settings to the `groupplot` environment, instead of repeating it for each `\nextgroupplot`.
- Instead of adding `\footnotesize` in each `xtick`, I change the `x tick label style`.
- Instead of having the text outside the `tikzpicture`, I add them as nodes placed relative to the axes. By adding `group name=some string` to the `group style`, each subaxis will become a named node, so `some string c1r2` is the axis in the first column and second row of the grid. Further, `some string c1r2.north west` will be the top right corner of this. The text is placed relative to such coordinates.

[image: output of below code]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
    \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\tikzset{
   sigmalabel/.style={font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt, above},
   tissue/.style={fill=green!70!black, draw=none},
   ubiq/.style={fill=yellow!60!black, draw=none},
   plotline/.style={cyan!50!black}
   }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
   group style={
      group size=3 by 2,
      group name=mydist,
      vertical sep=2cm,
      horizontal sep=10pt},
   width=5cm,
   height=3cm,
   no markers,
   samples=100,
   axis lines*=left,
   ytick=\empty,
   enlargelimits=false,
   clip=false,
   axis on top,
   x tick label style={font=\footnotesize}]

% start of tissue-specific plots
\nextgroupplot[
    domain=0:12,
    xtick={2,8},
    xticklabels={$\mu 1$,$\mu 2$}
    ]

  \addplot [tissue, domain=2.75:3.65] {gauss(2,0.5)}
  \closedcycle;
  \addplot [tissue, domain=4.9:6.5] {gauss(8,1)}
  \closedcycle;
  \addplot [plotline] {gauss(2,0.5)};
  \addplot [plotline] {gauss(8,1)};

  \addplot[<->] coordinates {(1.25,0.2) (2.75,0.2)};
  \node at (axis cs: 2,0.2) [sigmalabel] {$\sigma 1$};
  \addplot[<->] coordinates {(6.5,0.12) (9.5,0.12)};
  \node at (axis cs: 8,0.12) [sigmalabel] {$\sigma 2$};

\nextgroupplot[
    domain=0:25,
    xtick={2,8,19},
    xticklabels={$\mu 1$,$\mu 2$,$\mu 3$}
    ]

  \addplot [tissue, domain=2.75:3.65] {gauss(2,0.5)}
  \closedcycle;
  \addplot [tissue, domain=4.9:6.5] {gauss(8,1)}
  \closedcycle;
  \addplot [tissue, domain=9.5:11.1] {gauss(8,1)}
  \closedcycle;
  \addplot [tissue, domain=13:16] {gauss(19,2)}
  \closedcycle;
  \addplot [plotline] {gauss(2,0.5)};
  \addplot [plotline] {gauss(8,1)};
  \addplot [plotline] {gauss(19,2)};

  \addplot[<->] coordinates {(1.25,0.2) (2.75,0.2)};
  \node at (axis cs: 2,0.2) [sigmalabel] {$\sigma 1$};
  \addplot[<->] coordinates {(6.5,0.12) (9.5,0.12)};
  \node at (axis cs: 8,0.12) [sigmalabel] {$\sigma 2$};
  \addplot[<->] coordinates {(16,0.04) (22,0.04)};
  \node at (axis cs: 19,0.04) [sigmalabel] {$\sigma 3$};


\nextgroupplot[
    domain=0:25,
    xtick={2,5,19},
    xticklabels={$\mu 1$,$\mu 2$,$\mu 3$}
    ]

  \addplot [tissue, domain=2.75:3.65] {gauss(2,0.5)}
  \closedcycle;
  \addplot [tissue, domain=2:3.5] {gauss(5,1)}
  \closedcycle;
  \addplot [tissue, domain=6.5:8] {gauss(5,1)}
  \closedcycle;
  \addplot [tissue, domain=13:16] {gauss(19,2)}
  \closedcycle;
  \addplot [plotline] {gauss(2,0.5)};
  \addplot [plotline] {gauss(5,1)};
  \addplot [plotline] {gauss(19,2)};

  \addplot[<->] coordinates {(1.25,0.2) (2.75,0.2)};
  \node at (axis cs: 2,0.2) [sigmalabel] {$\sigma 1$};
  \addplot[<->] coordinates {(3.5,0.12) (6.5,0.12)};
  \node at (axis cs: 5,0.12) [sigmalabel] {$\sigma 2$};
  \addplot[<->] coordinates {(16,0.04) (22,0.04)};
  \node at (axis cs: 19,0.04) [sigmalabel] {$\sigma 3$};


% start of ubiquitous plots
\nextgroupplot[
    domain=0:10,
    xtick=5,
    xticklabels={$\mu 1$}
    ]

  \addplot [ubiq, domain=1.5:3.5] {gauss(5,1)}
  \closedcycle;
  \addplot [ubiq, domain=6.5:8.5] {gauss(5,1)}
  \closedcycle;
  \addplot [plotline] {gauss(5,1)};

  \addplot[<->] coordinates {(3.5,0.1) (6.5,0.1)};
  \node at (axis cs: 5,0.1) [sigmalabel] {$\sigma 1$};


\nextgroupplot[
     domain=0:10,
     xtick={3,6},
     xticklabels={$\mu 1$,$\mu 2$}
     ]

  \addplot [ubiq, domain=3.75:4.65] {gauss(3,0.5)}
  \closedcycle;
  \addplot [ubiq, domain=2.5:4.5] {gauss(6,1)}
  \closedcycle;
  \addplot [plotline] {gauss(3,0.5)};
  \addplot [plotline] {gauss(6,1)};

  \addplot[<->] coordinates {(2.25,0.2) (3.75,0.2)};
  \node at (axis cs: 3,0.2) [sigmalabel] {$\sigma 1$};
  \addplot[<->] coordinates {(4.5,0.12) (7.5,0.12)};
  \node at (axis cs: 6,0.12) [sigmalabel] {$\sigma 2$};


\nextgroupplot[
     domain=0:15,
     xtick={2,5,10},
     xticklabels={$\mu 1$,$\mu 2$,$\mu 3$}
     ]

  \addplot [ubiq, domain=2.75:3.65] {gauss(2,0.5)}
  \closedcycle;
  \addplot [ubiq, domain=2:3.5] {gauss(5,1)}
  \closedcycle;
  \addplot [ubiq, domain=6.5:8] {gauss(5,1)}
  \closedcycle;
  \addplot [ubiq, domain=4:6.9] {gauss(10,2)}
  \closedcycle;
  \addplot [plotline] {gauss(2,0.5)};
  \addplot [plotline] {gauss(5,1)};
  \addplot [plotline] {gauss(10,2)};

  \addplot[<->] coordinates {(1.25,0.2) (2.75,0.2)};
  \node at (axis cs: 2,0.2) [sigmalabel] {$\sigma 1$};
  \addplot[<->] coordinates {(3.5,0.12) (6.5,0.12)};
  \node at (axis cs: 5,0.12) [sigmalabel] {$\sigma 2$};
  \addplot[<->] coordinates {(7,0.04) (13,0.04)};
  \node at (axis cs: 10,0.04) [sigmalabel] {$\sigma 1$};

\end{groupplot}

\node at (mydist c1r1.north west) [above right,green!70!black] {Tissue-specific expression};
\node at (mydist c1r1.south west) [below right,yshift=-2ex,font=\footnotesize] {$\alpha/2=0.025$};

\node at (mydist c1r2.north west) [above right,green!70!black] {Ubiquitous expression};
\node at (mydist c1r2.south west) [below right,yshift=-2ex,font=\footnotesize] {$\alpha/2=0.025$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## Converting to PNG

The `standalone` class allows you to have your `tikzpicture`s converted to PNG directly. This requires that ImageMagick is installed, see the manual for details. Start by removing everything outside the `tikzpicture` environments from the `document` environment, and adding e.g. `tikz,convert={density=150}` to the options of the class. When compiling you have to enable `shell-escape`. The code would look something like

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
...
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
...
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Each `tikzpicture` will be given a separate page in the PDF, and a separate PNG is created.